# passing parameter from asp.net page to flex application

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex

I have an asp.net page where I get the user_id from who's logged in. Now I need to pass this user_id to a flex application that runs in an asp.net page as a .swf. 
How can I get this user_id in a variable in my flex application.
Or what is the best way to get the user_id into flex.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You make another asp.net page and on this page u get that userid and write on the page.
from the flex application hit that asp.net page with the HTTPService and get that response.
in  that response u get that user id...

```
var httpservice:HTTPService=new HTTPService();
     httpservice.url="http://xyz.com/getuser.aspx;
     httpservice.useProxy=false;
     httpservice.method="Post";
     httpservice.resultFormat="text";
     httpservice.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,GettingException);
     httpservice.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,Result);
     httpservice.send();


private function GettingException(e:FaultEvent){

 Alert.show(e.fault.message, "Could not load page");

}
 private function Result(e:ResultEvent){

 var Result:String = e.result.toString();
 Alert.show(Result);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you link to the ASP.Net page that holds the swf, you could obfuscate the user_id and pass it in the querystring, or use a guid that maps to the user_id.  Flex can read the value from the querystring.  See [this article.](http://flexed.wordpress.com/2006/10/25/get-url-query-string-variables-within-flex-application/)

Or you could paste the user_id value into the flashvars (the ASP.Net page should have access) and read it from there.

```
userID = Application.application.parameters.user_id;
```